# How to set input limit text after setting max length of TextField in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using `Flutter` for building iOS app. With `TextField`, I set max length of `TextField` is 4. Then, I input 8 words, but It (TextFiled) show 4 words and hide 4 words.

[image: bug_textfield]

This is my code:

```
TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          onChanged: (text) {
            print("text change: $text");
          },
          onSubmitted: (text) {
            print("text submit: $text");
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Input Money',
            counterText: '',
          ),
          maxLength: 4,
        )
```

When user delete words on TextField, They must delete 8 words.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this bug with bellow code:

```
                      TextField(
                          controller: _controller,
                          maxLength: 4,
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            text = text.substring(0, 4);
                            _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
                              text: text,
                              selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                                offset: text.length,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

You must set `selection` for text.

Answer (score 0):

use `TextFormField` instead, you can use a validator to warn user about input limit.

At first declare a key

```
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _textFieldOneKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
```

then validate it.It will give a warning to the user,whenever they trying to input more than 4 words!

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
    key: _textFieldOneKey,
    onChanged: (value) {
      _textFieldOneKey.currentState.validate();
      print("text submit: $value");
    },
    validator: (value) {
      if(value.length>4) {
        return "Max 4 word is allowed";
      }
      return null;
    },
    // maxLength: 4, 
  ),
```

You can check the illustration here
[image]

And you can check if the field is valid or not in any button or function like this one

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: (){
      if(_textFieldOneKey.currentState.isValid) {
        print("valid");
      } else {
        print("not valid");
      }
    },
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
```